# Filters - Ignore the other requests excluding the welcome file

Tags: java, jsp, filter, web.xml

I wrote a filter to decide user landing page before it reach my welcome-file. The welcome-file is written in such a way that it takes input from the filter and navigate the user to a specific page.

My welcome-file tag is...

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and my filter configuration is

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LandingPageFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.mypack.test.filters.LandingPageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LandingPageFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The above format is working good whilst every request is passing through this filter, which I want to avoid. When I hit `http://localhost:8000/landing` it should reach the filter for the first time only and later even if I access `http://localhost:8000/landing/edit` it should actually execute the relevant servlet bypassing the filter.

I tried this as well `<url-pattern>/*/index.jsp</url-pattern>` but no use. Why I use this because the **context** may vary but the app would be same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`<url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>`

instead of

`<url-pattern>/*/index.jsp</url-pattern>`

So your filter mapping part will become like this

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LandingPageFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Irrespective of the context this works because `/` represents the path after the context path.

For example if you have two context paths say **a** and **b** with two deployments of same application in your server and you are accessing them using the URLs

`http://localhost:8000/a/`

and

`http://localhost:8000/b/`

then `/` in the `url-pattern` represents `/` after context roots `a` and `b`. So your filter will be executed only for index.jsp.